# How to get the variance of a regression prediction in xgboost?

Tags: regression, xgboost

I want to know how well a prediction is by looking at the variance. Does xgboost provide a variance output for regression?

Comment: Xgboost works with several different languages, do hou have any preferences for language?

Comment: not really, currently I am using a binding for rust

Comment: what kind of variance are you interested in? In a sense, what would it be evaluated on? I'm not aware of a dedicated procedure for GBMs, as learnig iterations are incremental. In contrast, in random forest model one could simply evaluate the variance over all trees (the main prediction being the average over the same trees)

Comment: given a current leaf, I need to just calculate the variance of all the data points in the current leaf right?

Comment: but there is the problem of ensemble trees, where it will have multiple leafs and some weighted avg between the trees

Comment: Indeed, this definition works well for a single decision tree, it is more difficult to extend it to a random forest of trees and I'm not aware how to use it in GBMs :(

Comment: The implementation for RF is [link](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/_modules/skopt/learning/forest.html#ExtraTreesRegressor.predict). An attempt with quantiles for boosted trees is at [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-prediction-intervals-with-xgboost-428e0a018b?). A deleted repo for catboost implementation is [link](https://github.com/StatMixedML/CatBoostLSS)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can estimate the variance directly, but you could try to use [Quantile Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) to estimate the [IQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range), which is related with the variance. Then, instead of estimating the mean of the predicted variable, you could estimate the 75th and the 25th percentiles, and find IQR = p_75 - p_25.

This [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-prediction-intervals-with-xgboost-428e0a018b?) gives an implementation in python of Quantile Regression for XGBoost, which basically boils down to using a [check function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321857/quantile-regression-check-function) as the cost function, instead of the usual mean squared error.